# How to resolve "The requested URL/mypath was not found on this server?"

Tags: php, database, connection, wampserver

i have download wampserver and successfully installed it on my computer. However, when i am trying to connect to my database,it says the following:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /uomwebapplication/init was not found on this
>   server.
>
> Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80.

Help me on this please.

```
init.php


  <?php
  $db_name="uomwebappdb";
  $mysql_user="root";
  $mysql_pass="root";
  $server_name="localhost";

  $con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);
  if(!$con)
   {
  echo"Connection Error...".mysqli_connect_error();
   }
  else
  {
  echo"<h3>Database connection Success...</h3>";
 }




 ?>
```

Comment: check your project path is correct and wamp server working properly ?

Comment: yes my project path is good and wampserver is working properly but still getting same problem.

Comment: you want to check your wamp server is in green symbol after running and you set online wampserver ?

Comment: Yes the wampserver is green and working properly.

Comment: your localhost and phpmyadmin working ? or check permission issue possible

Comment: How and where do i check that? How can i know if this is working?

Comment: run only localhost in your browser or your ip its saw you wamp details also try localhost/phpmyadmin or servernip/phpmyadmin and check its open or not

Comment: Manually enter this as the url in the browser `localhost//uomwebapplication/init` what happens then

Comment: @jilesh both is opening correctly.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it still gives me same error

Comment: How about if you do just `localhost/uomwebapplication`

Comment: @RiggsFolly:i got this as error:  Connection Error...Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). How do i correct this? i pasted my code above.

Comment: @jilesh:casual name for the php file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: your database credentials are wrong please correct it put your db_name , mysql_user,mysql_pass and server_name as per your database

Comment: @jilesh Thanks but its not my database its akshay's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, by default MYSQL is installed with one user called `root` and this user has no password, so change this code to

```
<?php
  $db_name="uomwebappdb";
  $mysql_user="root";
  $mysql_pass="";          //<-- changed here
  $server_name="localhost";

  $con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);
  if(!$con) {
      echo"Connection Error...".mysqli_connect_error();
  } else {
      echo"<h3>Database connection Success...</h3>";
  }
```

Comment: Great at last it worked! thanks a lot! upvoted your answer.